# JavaScript: Best format for timestamps

Tags: javascript, mongodb, datetime, meteor, momentjs

I'd like to set createdAt and updatedAt values on my db entries.

I've looked around and found a couple formats I can use.

- `new Date()`   : "Wed Nov 26 2014 15:01:23 GMT+0100 (CET)"
- `Date.now()`   : "1417010450615"
- `moment()`       : "1417010499341"
- `moment().unix()`: "1417010509"

I'm currently saving time information using `moment().unix()`, but `Date.now()` or just `moment()` seem to be more precise. I think that all formats give me an "absolute time".

Is there a preferred format for saving time information and why? Or is it up to the personal preference?

Thank you!

Comment: If you ask me, ISO is the best format

Comment: I believe `moment()` is just a wrapper for a `Date()` object. Why not just store the date in the `Date` field type for the mongo db and let the db handle the format?

Comment: For my specific application is used `Date.now()` due to the specific functionally of meteor application. I was bringing in files and exporting them with the date being of high importance. The program that took-in the exported files needed the date to be in a certain format and would not be able to place them in sequential order if the time format was not correct. So In short, I would say it is up to your app's functionality and/or personal preference.

Comment: I just had a look at Meteor's user collection, it uses ISODate. How can I store a date like this? And what's the difference to a string?

Comment: It's a `Date` object. See [this line](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/58869b050bf5cdc77991505b10c46112d85aff24/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js#L1015) where user accounts get inserted. `ISODate` is how it's represented once it is stored in mongo. It looks like a string when you inspect it in the shell, but internally it's a date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not normally so unequivocal in my answers, but storing your times as `Date` objects is the correct choice. Dates are:

- searchable - $gt, $lt, etc. all work
- serializable and deserializable by EJSON
- available - you don't have to convert them after fetching an object
- complete - they encapsulate both time and timezone infomation

All other choices fall short in some way. For a complete overview of all things time-related for meteor, see [this hackpad](https://meteor.hackpad.com/Meteor-Cookbook-Using-Dates-and-Times-qSQCGFc06gH).

Answer (score 0):

In meteorjs i prefer to save them as string yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss. It makes sorting very easy. I think its more of a preference choice.

Comment: Storing it as a string is the least good way. For example, you'll get in trouble with daylight saving time, and if you want to present the date in another format, you'll have to do some extra work. Storing it as a date (which is fine because it's part of EJSON) or as a unix timestamp is a better alternative.

Comment: Yes but the only thing is that you would need to write a function to read and write the date to the desired string. Its about 3 lines of code. Yes ofc you can use the timestamp but string works fine for the reason that you control exactly how it is entered in the db.